# C++ statement "if" is ignore

Tags: c++

when I debug and run the program, it ignores the "if" statement and ends the program. I reviewed it but did not know where was wrong?
this is the program I write (factorial)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void factorial(int n)
{
    int result;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        result = result * (n - 1);
    }
}
int main()
{   
    int n, result;
    cout << " n: ";
    cin >> n;

    if (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (n = 0)
    {
        cout << "0! = 0" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (n > 0)
    {
        factorial(n);
        cout << n << "! = " << result << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Does this program have errors and how to fix them?

Comment: please explain. What makes you think that the `if` is ignored? What is the input?

Comment: There is a huge difference between `=` and `==`, and modern compilers usually warn you about this mistake.

Comment: Please enable your compiler warnings. Your compiler will spot the typo in `if (n = 0)` much easier than us, humans.

Comment: with the right flags for the compiler your code does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/EnaMa6. The compiler is your friend, use it!

Comment: Long ago I heard recommendation that you should always write conditions the other way around so that even if you make a typo compiler will warn you. Instead of `n == 0` turn it into `0 == n`. I rarely use this approach, but here it would help.

Comment: Also you seem to have misunderstanding about how functions work. `factorial` doesn't return anything, don't expect it to magically change the variable `result` that's defined in `main`!

Comment: Also, the factorial of 0 is 1.

Comment: In addition to what's been said already, you're using `result` uninitialized in `factorial`.

Comment: And your calculation of the factorial is wrong. `n!` is not equal to `(n-1) * (n-1) * ... * (n-1)`; it's equal to `1 * 2 * ... * n`.

Comment: In main() function, " else if ( n = 0) " will always ignored. Like if enter 0 for n still that block not executed. " if (n = 0) " is like " if ( 0 ) ", which is always false and thus next else block will executed. Also your " factorial (int) " function is wrong. It will not give correct factorial. Let me know if you want to get correct factorial code.

Comment: it would really help if you mention WHICH if has the problem. Why haven't you tried a debugger and see what happens to your variables

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use operator `=` instead of `==` in `if else`. Change `else if (n = 0)` to `else if (n == 0)`

`=` is assignment operator, `==` is comparison operator. In `if else` you need to compare value of `n` with `0`, to assign `0` to `n`